# Conditional require in Sprockets

Tags: ruby, sprockets

How can I conditionally require assets using Sprockets?

I've googled for solutions before asking and found this discussion in the Sprockets repository - [Conditional require](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/90)

The solution discussed there is to use ERB:

```
<% require_asset "#{ActiveScaffold.js_framework}/my_test" %>
```

I've tried it this way:

**app.js.erb**

```
<% if debug == true %>
   <% require_asset "lib-debug" %>
<% else %>
   <% require_asset "lib-min" %>
<%end%>
```

**Rakefile**

```
def bundle_app(debug)
  env = Sprockets::Environment.new
  env.append_path "app/"
  env.js_compressor = Uglifier.new
  assets = env.find_asset("app.js.erb")
  return assets.to_s
end
```

But it results in the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `debug' for #<#:0x00000001576d30>

Definitely there is some easy-to-fix error, but I'm new to Ruby and just can't spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to add the following into the bundle_app method:

```
env.context_class.class_eval "def debug; #{!!debug}; end"
```

The updated bundle_app() method:

```
def bundle_app(debug)
  env = Sprockets::Environment.new
  env.append_path "app/"
  env.context_class.class_eval "def debug; #{!!debug}; end"
  env.js_compressor = Uglifier.new
  assets = env.find_asset("app.js.erb")
  return assets.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, since your example uses debug as a parameter, you could use settle for having the asset in the development environment?

If so, in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.assets.precompile << 'lib-debug.js'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! But I'd prefer to make such decisions directly in the JS code, so that my build file is kept unaware of the application affairs.